# Integrating refinerycms into existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

I am trying to integrate refinerycms with my existing rails application(my app uses devise).
Followed this [tutorial](http://sdownie.com/articles/refinerycms-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-app) and got this error when run the command `rails g refinery:cms --fresh-installation`

```
==  AddSourceUrlToBlogPosts: migrating ========================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Refinery::User/home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'

gem "devise", "~> 2.2.3"

gem "refinerycms-core", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "refinerycms-dashboard", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "refinerycms-images", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "refinerycms-pages", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "refinerycms-resources", "~> 2.1.0"
gem 'refinerycms-blog', :git => 'git@github.com:refinery/refinerycms-blog.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official guide for the exact environment that you describe:

[Using Refinery with Rails 3.1 and Devise](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-31-devise-app)

It doesn't even assume you have already the app working. The guide goes from creating the app and adding Devise to installing Refinery on top of that.